# how to show selected value in php page as shown below?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

i make a php page in which i show the selected value,selected value check from post array here is my array:

```
Array ( [events] => Array [fromdate] => [todate] => [description] => [subject] => [fromname] => [replyto] => [senddatetime] => [timezone] => America/Los_Angeles [message] =>
```

dfhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
[submit_skip] => Continue )

i want to get events array and compare option value with events array if events array value matched with options then it shown selected like the given below:

[image]

here is my code:

```
 <select name="events[]" multiple size="10" >
        <?
        $events = array();
        $events=$_POST['events'];
        $select = sprintf ("SELECT event_id,event_name
                        FROM `events`
                        WHERE (`user_id` = '%s') order by event_name",
                        $GLOBALS ['mysqli']->real_escape_string ($_SESSION['user_id']));

        $res = $GLOBALS ['mysqli']->query ($select) or die ($GLOBALS ['mysqli']->error . __LINE__);
        if ($res->num_rows > 0)
        {

            while($row = $res->fetch_assoc ())
            {
                if($row['event_id']== $_POST['events'])
                $selected = "selected=\"selected\"";
                else
                $selected = "";
                echo "<option value=\"".$row['event_id']."\" $selected>".$row['event_name']."</option>\n ";
            }
        }           
        ?>
        </select>
```

Comment: what is the question here? you seem to accomplish what you ask for, if the data is correct.

Comment: i want to show selected options but not shown

Comment: you need to give us more data. your code will show all your database rows in that select but the compare with in_array is wrong. your event arrays first element has many keys but none but one has value. and you are comparing that value with event_id. that is wrong. please provide us what data you have in your db and full php array you are comparing with. also what you expect to get and what you get with this code.

Comment: i edit my code see code again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your post array does not contain any event_id data so this compare won't work. if you had something like this:

```
Array ( [events] => Array [0] => 3 [1] => 5 [2] => 4 )
```

then you could compare with this:

```
if(in_array($row['event_id'], $_POST['events'])
```